# Reading .log files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I have the following output from a .log file

```
Date/Time: 2019-09-11 13:11:48
Global Freq. Table [Ticks @ 82.3045ps]
  -1215 : 56
  -1214 : 192
  -1213 : 105
  -1212 : 375
  -1211 : 230
```

I would like to know how can I write a python script to first read the columns read the values separated by the : and store them into separate arrays. I appreciate if you could give me a hand on that.

Comment: Try `regex` to extract pattern like `XXX : XXX`, you will get 2 groups separated by `:`, can you try it and update here.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have a file (**file.log**) with the content:

```
Date/Time: 2019-09-11 13:11:48 Global Freq. Table [Ticks @ 82.3045ps] -1215 : 56 -1214 : 192 -1213 : 105 -1212 : 375 -1211 : 230
Date/Time: 2019-09-11 13:11:48 Global Freq. Table [Ticks @ 82.3045ps] -1215 : 56 -1214 : 192 -1213 : 105 -1212 : 375 -1211 : 230
Date/Time: 2019-09-11 13:11:48 Global Freq. Table [Ticks @ 82.3045ps] -1215 : 56 -1214 : 192 -1213 : 105 -1212 : 375 -1211 : 230
```

First you open the file:

```
file = open('file.log', 'r')
```

You read all the lines from the file, and then you close it:

```
lines = file.read().splitlines()
file.close()
```

Since the columns are clearly separated by the **:** character, it's simple to get each column separately:

```
for line in lines:
    if not line:
        continue

    columns = [col.strip() for col in line.split(':') if col]

    # do something
```

Now the column variable contains all the columns you needed.

Comment: To gather all the data in the file you can add this after the columns assignment line:
data.append( columns )

Then return data which will be a multidimensional array containing all the column data for each line